# Markdown CMS platform?

Tags: cms, markdown

What are some good simple CMS program that support markdown? Namely, I want to create documentation/tutorials for various things at my company and I want something that:

1. I can setup easily
2. Looks nice
3. Let's me edit a page directly from the browser
4. Let's me somehow backup the markdown in raw format (in case of the platform crashing)

So far I've found [Harp](http://harpjs.com/), [Strapdown.js](http://strapdownjs.com/) and [Luminos](https://menteslibres.net/luminos/) but would like to hear what others have to recommend and why.

Comment: What do you mean with "platforms"? Websites? If yes, with backend (editing in the browser), or via uploading Markdown files (editing in a local editor)?

Comment: @unor well I am not sure what I am looking for. I want something that looks like read-the-docs or github's wiki, that I can run on my own server.

Comment: [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) has a Markdown editor integrated. Might be interesting if you'd like to have a calendar, address book, file storage, etc. as by-products.

Comment: @Izzy that is simply an upload/download cloud service. I want something closer to Githubs wiki without all the bloat.

Comment: Is it? Well, my installation must be different then (I'm using ownCloud on my own server). The basic install came with all what I've mentioned above – including the integrated MD editor. But I can see that the "side effects" are a bit heavy if you want *only* the MD editor. So let me suggest something different: Must the editor be a web-service, or can it be [a stand-alone app](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=markdown+editor+answers%3A1 "Markdown Editor questions with answers") as well?

Comment: It sounds like you want a wiki. Do you have any particular constraints on who can edit each page? Usually the kind of documentation you'd put on a web page in a company is stuff needs to be editable by anyone who changes it. Also, is markdown itself necessary, or are similar mini-markup languages ok (in which case just about any wiki would do)?

Comment: @Izzy well trying the [demo](http://demo.owncloud.org) it feels just like a file browser. I don't want people to have to browse and open files.

Comment: @Gilles I would go with wiki but there are two problems. All people using the platform will be developers so they are already comfortable with markdown. Secondly, wiki seemed a bit bloated last time I used it (and ugly). But you are close to what I want. I want a very simplified wiki that supports markdown out-of-the-box and looks slick.

Comment: @Pithikos no idea about the demo, as I cannot even log into that (no credentials; tried demo/demo, but that didn't work). See [some screenshots](https://www.google.com/search?q=owncloud+editor&ie=UTF-8&nfpr=1&tbm=isch), especially [this one](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/56051499d2fb0fa52817597e0f49059ac95ffa98/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f5541496f634e5a2e706e67).

Comment: @Pithikos How is wiki bloated? They come in all sizes and shapes. And what on earth does “looks slick” mean? Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: @Gilles Bloated visually. It's simply hard to the eyes. With slick I mean something minimal, beautiful and intuitive. Here's an example: http://logdown.com

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found two candidates:

1. [Logdown](https://logdown.com)
2. [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) with [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com)

Logdown is just a cool technical cloud blogging tool. That takes away some freedom..

For that reason I chose the second choice which is essentially Github's free hosting for webpages. It has quite some work to get it work with markdown but it gives you freedom.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Yellow](http://datenstrom.se/yellow/) could meet your needs. There is a demo at that link, or you can see the [documentation](https://github.com/datenstrom/yellow/wiki) on Github. Here's how it meets the criteria:

- [image: Yes] I can setup easily | **Copy files to your server (needs PHP). Done.**
- [image: Yes] Looks nice | [image: Note] **See the available themes; can be tweaked, of course.**
- [image: Yes] Let's me edit a page directly from the browser | **Yes - this is what attracted me to Yellow in the first place.**
- [image: Yes] Let's me somehow backup the markdown in raw format (in case of the platform crashing) | **It's just folders and files: back up any way you want.**

I've trialled this and used it for a small course-website. Works a treat. It's GPLv2 licensed.